# Why is the formula for the number of non-negative solutions to an equation ${x_1 + x_2 +... + x_r = n}$ not ${r^n}$

Tags: combinatorics

Good Day! How are you doing?

I recently learnt that the formula for the number of non-negative solutions to the equation ${x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n}$ is ${n+r-1 \choose r-1}$. It can also be easily proven using the circles and bars (or whatever you wanna call it). But my reasoning was as follows:

To find the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation ${x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n}$, suppose that there are $n$ balls and $r$ boxes to put it. Then the number of ways to put the $n$ balls into $r$ boxes is ${r^n}$ (There are $r$ ways to put the balls into the boxes). But this is clearly different.

I know I am over-counting but I don't know how exactly. I would be grateful to you if you helped me. I know I am missing out on something and not realizing it. This question may sound stupid or trivial to you, but I am just not able to realize where I am over-counting.

Thanks!

Comment: You are assuming the balls are all different (distinguishable).

Comment: The correct expression is $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ or $\binom{n+r-1}n$.

Comment: @user It depends on whether $n$ represents the number of balls and $r$ the number of bins, or if it is the other way around with $n$ representing the number of *bins* and $r$ the number of *balls*.  $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ is a perfectly correct result if you use the corresponding choice of what $n,r$ stand for.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210062/whats-the-difference-between-the-following-nk-1-choose-k-nk-1-choosek/3210073#3210073).

Comment: Try a simple example like $n=2,r=2$ and see why the number of non-negative solutions to the equation is $3$ rather than $4$.  Then consider your balls and boxes and @MichalAdamaszek's comment to see why the balls are indistinguishable here

Comment: @JMoravitz $n$ and $r$ are not arbitrary. They are defined in the question  so that $n$ counts "balls" and $r$ counts "bins".

Comment: @user I concede that the question is currently worded in such a way as to have $n$ as the number of balls and $r$ as the number of bins and the correct answer to the question as written is $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$.  My point was that it makes sense for the OP to have made the mistake of writing $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ instead as this would be the correct expression in the case that the roles of $n$ and $r$ are reversed, such as in the original form of the title where rather than it being written $x_1+\dots+x_r=n$ it was written as $x_1+\dots+x_n=r$.  My goal was to help clarify the differences in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following questions are all different and with different answers:

- How many ways can you distribute $n$ **distinct** balls among $r$ **distinct** boxes? 
  $r^n$
- How many ways can you distribute $n$ **indistinct** balls among $r$ **distinct** boxes?  $\binom{r+n-1}{n}$
- How many ways can you distribute $n$ **distinct** balls among $r$ **indistinct** boxes?  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^r \left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\}$
- How many ways can you distribute $n$ **indistinct** balls among $r$ **indistinct** boxes?  $p_r(n+r)$

You were confusing the original problem with the first of these where your balls were distinct when it should have been in the second case where the balls were in fact considered indistinct.

Read more about these and the notations used and other similar problem variants where you require at least or at most one ball in each bin at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way.