# An exact formula for counting solutions of the Frobenius equation summed to 8

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations, diophantine-equations, combinatorial-proofs

Let us consider a Frobenius equation with:
$$
x_1+\dots+x_n=8, \tag{1}$$
where $$(x_1, \dots, x_n)$$ 
must consist of non-negative integers, i.e. 
$$
x_j \in \mathbb{N}
$$
as Natural numbers.

Here is my question:  Is there a general formula for Eq.(1) counting all the possible solutions $$(x_1, \dots, x_n)$$
for given the positive integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? This should be related to the [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), but I am not sure the exact forms are known? Say, can we find the total number of possible solutions as a function $f(n)$, and what is
$$
f(n)=?
$$

> I am interested in finding
>   $$
> f(20)=?
> $$
>   $$
> f(36)=?
> $$

p.s. Sorry if this question is too simple for number theorists. But please provide me answer and Refs if you already know the answer. Many thanks!

p.s.2. A more advanced generalized version of question is asked in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352331/request-for-an-exact-formula-related-to-a-partition-in-number-theory

Comment: Search this site for *stars and bars*.

Comment: See also: [Why is the formula for the number of non-negative solutions to an equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_r=n$
not $r^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226879)

Comment: @Rob Pratt, many thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

The number of solutions will be
\begin{eqnarray*}
[x^8]: (1+x+x^2+\cdots)^n = [x^8]: \frac{1}{(1-x)^n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use
\begin{eqnarray*}
[x^m]:  \frac{1}{(1-x)^n}= \binom{m+n-1}{n-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thanks very much, I think you are correct. +1 - will accept as an answer in 3 days --- any good refs for this answer? and for this question too https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352331/request-for-an-exact-formula-related-to-a-partition-in-number-theory ?