# Placing $r$ objects to $n$ persons without restriction

Tags: combinatorics

We distribute $r$ objects between $n$ persons without restriction on how many objects does $1$ person receive.

In how many ways can we do that.

The answer for if we make them distinguishable is: $n^r$, and if we make them indistinguishable is : $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$.

The second answer is similar to the theorem of any pair of positive integers $n$ and $k$, the number of $k-tuples$ of non-negative integers whose sum is $n$ is equal to the number of multisets of cardinality $k-1$ taken from a  set of size $n+1$.

However I do not have intuitive understanding of the answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @JMoravitz The theorem has $k-1$ in the lower of binomial symbol, but here it's only $k$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210062/whats-the-difference-between-the-following-nk-1-choose-k-nk-1-choosek/3210073#3210073  Make sure you can tell the difference between the statement "$r$ objects and $n$ persons"  and the statement "$n$ objects and $r$ persons."  Make sure you understand whether $n$ represents the number of bins or the number of balls in a formula you cite.