# How many possible sequences with length $N$ and $M$ characters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we are writing out binary sequences. Let a particular sequence have $n$ ones and $m$ zeroes.

a) How many possible such sequences are there?

There are ${n+m \choose n}$ to choose 1’s. Label the remaining $n+m-n=m$ bits with 0’s. There are ${m \choose m}=1$ ways to do this. There are ${n+m \choose n}$ possible sequences.

b) Now suppose we are writing out sequences with length $N$ and $M$ characters. How many unordered sequences are there?

I'm assuming this is talking about unordered sequences with replacement so that would just be ${N+M-1 \choose M}$

Would this be correct?

Comment: This is almost correct.  You had $\binom{N+M-1}{M}$ however instead of $\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}$ or $\binom{N+M-1}{N}$.  Keep track of which are your "balls" and which are your "bins" and recall that the bars in stars-and-bars is used as separators between the regions corresponding to the different bins... you need one fewer separator than bins.

Comment: Longer explanation: [Whats the difference between the following? $n+k-1 \choose k$ ${{n+k-1}\choose{k-1}}$ ${{n+k-1}\choose{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210062/whats-the-difference-between-the-following-nk-1-choose-k-nk-1-choosek/3210073#3210073)